# How to change OpenSuse repo urls to HTTPS?

Tags: opensuse, curl, repository, https

I want to change

```
http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/
```

to

```
https://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/
```

in yast -> software repositories -> edit -> edit parts of repo -> "x" the https (before it was plain http), but it just gives me the error message:

```
Download (curl) error for 'https://download.opensuse.org/update/tumbleweed/repo/repoindex.xml': 
Error code: Bad URL
Error message: Protocol "http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

But if I try via hand, both http and https fail:

```
linux-4tur:~ # curl https://download.opensuse.org/update/tumbleweed/repo/repoindex.xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory:/Update/standard/repo/repoindex.xml">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE) Server at download.opensuse.org Port 443</address>
</body></html>
linux-4tur:~ # curl http://download.opensuse.org/update/tumbleweed/repo/repoindex.xml
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/openSUSE:/Factory:/Update/standard/repo/repoindex.xml">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.12 (Linux/SUSE) Server at download.opensuse.org Port 80</address>
</body></html>
linux-4tur:~ #
```

Comment: Seems "Factory" has a new URL .   **Package_repositories#Factory_and_Project_repositories** : https://en.opensuse.org/Package_repositories#Factory_and_Project_repositories

Comment: how is this related to the question? via plain http it works. the problem is with https.

Comment: Sorry, got tumbleweed mixed up with "leap". Please follow the links : tumbleweed : I don't see any https, only http → http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/ . http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/suse/ . http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/suse/repodata/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using yast you could edit the `*.repo` text files below `/etc/zypp/repos.d/` with a text editor.

You can test via

```
$ zypper ref
```

BTW use `curl -L ...` to follow redirects.

Comment: Editing by hand worked! Thank you! only packman isn't available via HTTPS.. in 2017 :\

Comment: Note that there are many different mirrors for packman http://packman.links2linux.org/mirrors Some of may have https, e.g. gwdg.

Comment: Set the url to the https mirror (there's two atm: Germany/gwdg, United States/openSUSE). Otherwise the main repository can redirect you to the nearest http mirror.